Why are some fontawesome icons taller than others
I'm using fontawesome icons in one of my layouts. I'm aligning center, but the icon for "play" and "download" are taller than the icon for "stop". Why is this?


There's a difference between mathematically equal and visually balanced (and if you are talking about mathematically equal, why focus just on height? What about surface area or some other measurement?).
Evidently the designer of this icon set felt that the stop button should be a little shorter than the play button to be visually balanced. This coincides with a design principle called overshooting. For more, see this answer.
Most likely the designer compared multiple different icons next to each other when creating these icons and felt that this sizing was the most balanced in total.
But we can't say for sure without asking the designer.
